# How to get delta time to work on love2d

Tags: lua, love2d

Delta time wont work no matter what I try. I get this error

> player.lua 39: attempt to perform arithmetic on global 'dt' (a nil value)
>
> in function 'update'
>
> in function 'player_move'
>
> [C] in function: 'xpcall'

---

I did all the math right, it apparently thinks I'm talking about a non existent variable. Am I supposed to do `dt = 1` ?

If I do that it still looks like it's moving at different paces occasionally, and no tutorial or documentation I've seen tells you to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to initialize the dt variable, it is already done for you. If you are trying to get the Delta Time in the `love.update` function you do have access to the `dt` variable out of the box and wont run into any trouble, but this variable is not global so if you are trying to access this in another place ( Say your `love.draw` function or `player.lua` ) you have three other options:

## Use the Built in `love.timer.getDelta` function (Recommended)

This function is probably the best way to get the delta time. Here is an example usage:

```
whatever*love.timer.getDelta()
```

Pretty simple right!

## Make a Global delta time variable

This isn't really the best way to do it, but it is an option. Here is a way to do it and some example usage:

**In `love.update`:**

```
function love.update(dt)
  DeltaTime = dt
end
```

**Some Example Usage:**

```
whatever = whatever*DeltaTime
```

## Pass the Local dt variable to functions

This isn't a bad way to do it, the real problem with it is that it is that because you are calling your function from `love.update` so your function is getting called constantly ( and you might not want this. )

**In `love.update`:**

```
function love.update(dt)
  player_move(dt)
end
```

**Some Example Usage:**

```
function player_move(dt)
  whatever = whatever*dt
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you define `love.update` function as `love.update(dt)` (see the example on [love wiki](http://love2d.org/wiki/love.update)); if you call your `player_move` function from `love.update`, then you'll need to add `dt` as a parameter to `player_move` and pass the value to it:

```
local function player_move(dt)
  -- do something with dt
end

function love.update(dt)
  player_move(dt)
end
```